# Split nested dictionary in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames with a column named 'author' with a given format:

```
df1
author
{'name': 'Reuters Editorial', 'url': None}
df2
Authors 
{:name ""Arjun Sidharth"", :link ""https://www.altnews.in""}
```

I have tried the below code but it's not working:

```
 df1.explode('author')
```

I wanted to split the data into multiple columns, like the following:

```
df1
name URL
Reuters Editorial None

df2
name link
Arjun Sidharth https://www.altnews.in
```

Comment: The syntax for the dictionary in the second dataframe you give is invalid. If that's what you actually have and it's in the form of a string, something must be going wrong so that it's ended up that way. You would have to do some complicated regex to sort through it.

Comment: For example, do df2.str.replace(':name ""', 'name: ') and so forth

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values in df1 are dictionaries, you can map the values to two new columns:

```
df1['name'] = df1['author'].apply(lambda d: d['name'])
df1['url'] = df1['author'].apply(lambda d: d['url'])
```

If the values are strings like `"{'name': 'Reuters Editorial', 'url': None}"` you could use eval:

```
df1['name'] = df1['author'].apply(lambda d: eval(d)['name'])
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work for 2nd fataframe

Comment: Use some df2.str.replace() to make your 2nd dataframe look like a dictionary, then use eval as in df1

Comment: replace what?, in my knowledge, its doesn't look like a dictionary that' why I can not use split it

Comment: df2['authors'] is a series of strings that look like '{:name ""Arjun...' correct?  I'm saying the way those cells are formatted is useless so you need to edit all those strings to make them look like dictionaries.  Get rid of leading colon, double quotes, etc to make it look just like df1.  In other words you need to use df2['authors'].str.replace() a bunch of times to fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sam's answer is better & more concise, but here's another way of doing the same thing that might be useful in a given scenerio.

First, turn all dictionaries into lists of their values. For several columns, do this:

```
cols_with_dicts = [ ... list of dictionary columns ... ]

df[cols_with_dicts] = df[cols_with_dicts].applymap(
        lambda x: list(x.items())
    )
```

For just one column, like with `author`, just use `apply`:

```
df.author = df.author.apply(lambda x: list(x.items()))
```

Then, for each column, use list indexing to fill the right values into new columns:

```
df['name'] = df.author.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['url'] = df.author.apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: it gives error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: `cols_with_dicts` refers to a list of columns. It's for if you need to do this with multiple columns. For just one column, use apply and continue as usual.

Comment: thanks, again there is an error with one column, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Help us help you and post a sample of your data as a dictionary or pandas dataframe at the beginning of your question. Also see [ask] and [example].

Answer (score 0):

Added one more row in `df1` to explain better. Can be done in two steps -

[image: Two rows in df1]

Just fetch the names and URLs from the above and append to a list -

```
name = [i['name'] for i in df1['Author']]
url = [i['url'] for i in df1['Author']]
```

And assign those news lists to a new column -

```
df1['Name'] = name
df1['URL'] = url
```

Final Output -

[image: Final output]